# Why does a linear equation define a point-set of dimension one less than the space?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

For example:

If we are in 2-space (2 unknowns), a linear equation defines a line.
If we are in 3-space (3 unknowns), a linear equation defines a plane.

I mean, it seems obvious, but an explanation would clear it up.

Comment: it means the dimension as a projective space, because after a multiple, the equation defines the same divisor.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we have some equation with $n$ variables (assuming this is all over a field $\mathbb{F} $):

$$x_1 + x_2 +... + x_n = c $$

For some constant $c \in \mathbb{F}$.

Then, we can take this equation and subtract $x_n$, and $c$ from both sides:

$$-x_n = -c + x_1 + ... + x_{n-1} $$
$$\Leftrightarrow x_n = c - x_1 - ... - x_{n-1} $$

From here, any combination of values for the $n-1$ variables on the right determines the variable on the left. This means that the set of solutions for this equation is an $n-1 $ dimension vector space because each of the variables on the right are free.

Another way of looking at this kind of equation is, if you take a vector space $V$ over $\mathbb{F} $ with dimension $n-1 $, there exists a linear functional $l: V \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ in the dual of $V$ which acts on any vector $v \in V$ by summing the additive inverse of each entry in $v$.

In other words, for some $v = (x_1, x_2,...,x_{n-1})$

$$ <l,v> = - x_1 - x_2 - ... - x_{n-1} $$

If you combine this with the translation $g: \mathbb{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{F}$ such that $g(x) = x+c $,

$$ g(l(v)) = c + (- x_1 - ... - x_{n-1}) = c - x_1 - ... - x_{n-1} = x_n$$

This shows you that your original equation is uniquely determined by the mapping $g \circ l $, whose domain, the $n-1 $ dimensional vector space $V$, is exactly the solution set to the original equation.